# $in requires an array as a second argument, found: missing

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

can anybody please tell me what am i doing wrong?

db document structure:

```
{
    "_id" : "module_settings",
    "moduleChildren" : [
        {
            "_id" : "module_settings_general",
            "name" : "General",
        },
        {
            "_id" : "module_settings_users",
            "name" : "Users",
        },
        {
            "_id" : "module_settings_emails",
            "name" : "Emails",
        }
    ],
    “permissions” : [
        "module_settings_general",
        "module_settings_emails"
    ]
}
```

pipeline stage:

```
{ $project: {
    filteredChildren: {
        $filter: {
           input: "$moduleChildren",
           as: "moduleChild",
           cond: { $in : ["$$moduleChild._id", "$permissions"] }
        }
    },
}}
```

I need to filter "moduleChildren" array to show only modules which ids are in "permissions" array. Ive tried "$$ROOT.permissions" and "$$CURRENT.permissions" but none of them is working. I always get an error that $in is missing array as argument. It works when i hardcode the array like this: `cond: { $in : ["$$moduleChild._id", [“module_settings_general", "module_settings_emails”]] }` so it seems the problem is in passing of the array.
Thanks for any advices!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**First option** --> Use aggregation

Because your some of the documents in your collection may or may not contain **`permissions`**  field or is type not equal to array that's why you are getting this error.

You can find the [**`$type`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) of the field and if it is not an array or not exists in your document than you can add it as an array with [**`$addFields`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) and [**`$cond`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "permissions": {
      "$cond": {
        "if": {
          "$ne": [ { "$type": "$permissions" }, "array" ]
        },
        "then": [],
        "else": "$permissions"
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "filteredChildren": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$moduleChildren",
        "as": "moduleChild",
        "cond": {
          "$in": [ "$$moduleChild._id", "$permissions" ]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

**Second option** -->

Go to your mongo shell or robomongo on any GUI you are using and run 
this command

```
db.collection.update(
  { "permissions": { "$ne": { "$type": "array" } } },
  { "$set": { "permissions": [] } },
  { "multi": true }
)
```

Comment: Your second option wiped all of my arrays.  Thanks /s

Comment: @Arrow_Raider lol

Comment: reminder not to test in prod 