# $lookup with php mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, php-mongodb

I have a Student Table in mongo db like

```
      {
       "_id": ObjectId("5baa85f61d7859401000002a"),
        "Name": "Bella Dave",
         "RollNo": 12,
        "Class": "Ist",
        "TransportDetails": [
         {
            "RouteId": ObjectId("5baa93a21d7859401000002b"),
            "StopId": "abc123",
            "Status": "Inactive" 
         },
         {
            "RouteId": ObjectId("5baa818d1d78594010000029"),
            "StopId": "abc456",
            "Status": "Active" 
         } 
       ] 
     }
```

I have Route Table like

```
  {
     "Name": "New york City",
     "StopDetails": [
      {
        "StopId": "abc123",
        "Name": "Block no 1"
      },
     {
       "StopId": "abc567",
       "Name": "Block no 2"
     }
   ]
```

I have written below aggregation query like

```
       $cursor = $this->db->TblStudent->aggregate([
    [
        '$addFields' => [
            'ActiveRouteId' => [
                '$map' => [
                    'input' => '$TransportDetails',
                    'as' => 'item',
                    'in' => [
                        '$cond' => [
                            ['$eq' => ['$$item.Status', "Active"]],
                            '$$item.RouteId',
                            false
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
     [
        '$addFields' => [
            'ActiveStopId' => [
                '$map' => [
                    'input' => '$TransportDetails',
                    'as' => 'item',
                    'in' => [
                        '$cond' => [
                            ['$eq' => ['$$item.Status', "Active"]],
                            '$$item.StopId',
                            false
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
     array(
            '$lookup' => array(
                'from' => 'TblRoute',
                'localField' => 'ActiveRouteId',
                'foreignField' => '_id',
                'as' => 'RouteDetails'
            )
        ),
     array(
            '$lookup' => array(
                'from' => 'TblRoute',
                'localField' => 'ActiveStopId',
                'foreignField' => 'StopDetails.StopId',
                'as' => 'StopDetails'
            )
        ),
     ])->toArray();

    return $cursor;
```

Basically, I have to get active Route and Stop information along with student data. So, I successfully fetched ActiveRouteId and ActiveStopId using $addFields and $map operators. Based on ActiveRouteId, I am doing $lookup for fetching active route information. I am successfully getting that in "RouteDetails" embedded document. Now I issue is in the line

```
            array(
            '$lookup' => array(
                'from' => 'TblRoute',
                'localField' => 'ActiveStopId',
                'foreignField' => 'StopDetails.StopId',
                'as' => 'StopDetails'
            )
        ),
```

This lookup is not fetching anything. Please help!!!

Is it possible to find route and stop information together. I mean in route table there are many other embedded documents, if it is possible to fetch the  required embedded document like

```
      RouteDetails: [      
     "Name": "New york City",
     "StopDetails": [
      {
        "StopId": "abc123",
        "Name": "Block no 1"
      }
     ]
```

Comment: what is your mongodb version?

Comment: It is 3.6 version... Please help !!!

Comment: @ninda Please wait.

Comment: Thanks for being ready to help!!! Mongodb forum here is not responding to any problem

Comment: Have you found the mistake?

Comment: Yes, it is working fine now....

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: None of the data were matching the condition  { "$match": { "$expr": { "$in": ["$StopDetails.StopId", "$$activeStopId"] }}},
    ],

Comment: Once again thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below aggregation

```
TblStudent.aggregate([
  [ "$addFields"=> [
    "TransportDetails"=> [
      "$cond"=> [
        "if"=> [
          "$ne"=> [ [ "$type"=> "$TransportDetails" ], "array" ]
        ],
        "then"=> [],
        "else"=> "$TransportDetails"
      ]
    ]
  ]],
  [ "$addFields"=> [
    "ActiveRouteId"=> [
      "$filter"=> [
        "input"=> "$TransportDetails",
        "as"=> "item",
        "cond"=> [ "$eq"=> ["$$item.Status", "Active"] ]
      ]
    ]
  ]],
  [ "$lookup"=> [
    "from"=> "TblRoute",
    "let"=> [ "activeRouteId"=> "$ActiveRouteId.RouteId" ],
    "pipeline"=> [
      [ "$match"=> [ "$expr"=> [ "$in"=> ["$_id", "$$activeRouteId"] ]]]
    ],
    "as"=> "RouteDetails"
  ]],
  [ "$lookup"=> [
    "from"=> "TblRoute",
    "let"=> [ "activeStopId"=> "$ActiveRouteId.StopId" ],
    "pipeline"=> [
      [ "$unwind"=> "$StopDetails" ],
      [ "$match"=> [ "$expr"=> [ "$in"=> ["$StopDetails.StopId", "$$activeStopId"] ]]],
    ],
    "as"=> "StopDetails"
  ]]
])
```

Similar to javascript

```
TblStudent.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "TransportDetails": {
      "$cond": {
        "if": {
          "$ne": [ { "$type": "$TransportDetails" }, "array" ]
        },
        "then": [],
        "else": "$TransportDetails"
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "ActiveRouteId": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$TransportDetails",
        "as": "item",
        "cond": { "$eq": ["$$item.Status", "Active"] }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "TblRoute",
    "let": { "activeRouteId": "$ActiveRouteId.RouteId" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$in": ["$_id", "$$activeRouteId"] }}}
    ],
    "as": "RouteDetails"
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "TblRoute",
    "let": { "activeStopId": "$ActiveRouteId.StopId" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$unwind": "$StopDetails" },
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$in": ["$StopDetails.StopId", "$$activeStopId"] }}},
    ],
    "as": "StopDetails"
  }}
])
```

Gives me following output

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5baa85f61d7859401000002a"),
    "Name" : "Bella Dave",
    "RollNo" : 12,
    "Class" : "Ist",
    "TransportDetails" : [ 
        {
            "RouteId" : ObjectId("5baa93a21d7859401000002b"),
            "StopId" : "abc123",
            "Status" : "Inactive"
        }, 
        {
            "RouteId" : ObjectId("5baa818d1d78594010000029"),
            "StopId" : "abc456",
            "Status" : "Active"
        }
    ],
    "ActiveRouteId" : [ 
        {
            "RouteId" : ObjectId("5baa818d1d78594010000029"),
            "StopId" : "abc456",
            "Status" : "Active"
        }
    ],
    "routeDetails" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5baa818d1d78594010000029"),
            "Name" : "New york City",
            "StopDetails" : [ 
                {
                    "StopId" : "abc123",
                    "Name" : "Block no 1"
                }, 
                {
                    "StopId" : "abc567",
                    "Name" : "Block no 2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "StopDetails" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5baa93a21d7859401000002b"),
            "Name" : "New york City",
            "StopDetails" : {
                "StopId" : "abc456",
                "Name" : "Block no 2"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help but it is throwing error in the line  'pipeline' => [ telling message "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''pipeline'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')' in "  please help the solution is very near

Comment: Forgot to put `,`. Updated the answe please check

Comment: Sorry again... now it is throwing another error "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoDB\Driver\Exception\RuntimeException' with message ''ActiveStopId' starts with an invalid character for a user variable name' "

Comment: Please note that the lattest error is in vendor (driver of mongodb php)

Comment: please wait let me check.

Comment: are u able to find what is the is issue

Comment: Hi I have updated the answer. Tested with mongo shell. please give it a try.

Comment: Sorry it is again throwing the error message " Uncaught exception 'MongoDB\Driver\Exception\RuntimeException' with message ''ActiveRouteId' starts with an invalid character for a user variable name' in C:\xampp\htdocs\project_2.0\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\Operation\Aggregate.php"

Comment: Again sorry it is now throwing another error message in $in line "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoDB\Driver\Exception\RuntimeException' with message '$in requires an array as a second argument, found: missing' in C:\xampp\htdocs\project_2.0\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\Operation\Aggregate.php:22"

Comment: Are you using same ? Because I have tested in mongoshell. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51642472/in-requires-an-array-as-a-second-argument-found-missing/51645014#51645014

Comment: Yes i am using exactly your code and it is throwing error message in $in line of $match. I think now the solution is very near...

Comment: No man not possible we are passing second argument as an array in `$in` operator `["$_id", "$$activeRouteId"]`.

Comment: I realised now that there are some students where TransportDetails embedded document does not exist and are empty like TransportDetails [] or TransportDetails may contain all subdocuments with the Status Inactive. I removed all such students then it run without any error message but the StopDetails is comming empty in the case Where the status is Active

Comment: Since mongo db is schema free why it is throwing error message.... is it possible to make the above query to work in all cases.

Comment: Added one more stage. Give it a try

Comment: I am highly grateful to you for helping me and giving me so much of your time. Great help !!! Now it is working without throwing any error message... It is fetching RouteDetails successfully but StopDetails is appearing blank in all the case (also where the Status is active).

Comment: If` `{ "$in": ["$StopDetails.StopId", "$$activeStopId"] }` will match then it will definetly return the data. I have posted the result I am getting. Have a look at these two lines `{ "$unwind": "$StopDetails" },
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$in": ["$StopDetails.StopId", "$$activeStopId"] }}},`