# lookup on ObjectId's in an array

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have shops collection and user collection with list of shops ids inside of it as strings.

example of shop document:

```
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a0c6797fd3eb67969316ce2"),
            "picture" : "http://placehold.it/150x150",
            "name" : "Genmom",
            "email" : "leilaware@genmom.com",
            "city" : "Rabat",
            "location" : {
                    "type" : "Point",
                    "coordinates" : [
                            -6.79387,
                            33.83957
                    ]
            }
    }
```

example of user collection:

```
{
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c04b943ff491824b806686a"),
            "email" : "ayoub.khial@gmail.com",
            "password" : "$2a$10$4Wt5Rn6udxREdXCIt3hGb.sKhKUKOlyiYKmLTjYG3SqEPKFSw9phq",
            "likedShops" : [
                    "5a0c6797fd3eb67969316ce2",
                    "5c07ada8ff49183284e509d1",
                    "5c07acc1ff49183284e509d0"
            ],
            "dislikedShops" : [ ]
}
```

I want to return the detail of the likedShops.

Comment: What is the type of `likedShops` ids? String or OBjectID? And what version of mongo you are using?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet String

Comment: And the mongodb version?

Comment: mongodb  version 4.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use below [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#lookup-multiple-joins) aggregation

```
db.users.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "shops",
    "let": { "likedShops": "$likedShops" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$in": ["$_id", "$$likedShops"] }}}
    ],
    "as": "likedShops"
  }}
])
```

Or if your ids are string then use [**`$toString`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/) aggregation with the `ObjectIds`

```
db.users.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "shops",
    "let": { "likedShops": "$likedShops" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$in": [{ "$toString": "$_id" }, "$$likedShops"] }}}
    ],
    "as": "likedShops"
  }}
])
```

Comment: I'm getting `"errmsg" : "$in requires an array as a second argument, found: missing"`

Comment: by the way i have some users without likedShops field:)

Comment: Your some of the documents doesn't contain the `likedShop` field. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51642472/in-requires-an-array-as-a-second-argument-found-missing)