# MongoDB $lookup on one document's array of object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have searched online but could not find any match my case. Here is the situation.

I am using aggregate to combine one collection and one document which is from another collection together

```
restaurants.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: {
        $in: idList
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "tags",
      localField: "details.restaurantType",
      foreignField: "details.restaurantType._id",
      as: "types"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      restaurantName: "$details.restaurantName",
      restaurantType: "$details.restaurantType",
      type: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$types",
          as: "type",
          cond: {
            $eq: ["$$type._id", "$details.restaurantType"]
          }
        }
      },
      currency: "$details.currency",
      costPerPax: "$details.costPerPax"
    }
  }
]);
```

#### current result

The 'type' field in my current result is [], I need a matched value instead

```
[
    {
        "id": "5c20c7a0036dda80a8baabcc",
        "restaurantName": "Villagio Restaurant Sutera Mall",
        "type": [],
        "currency": "RM",
        "costPerPax": 22,
    },
    {
        "id": "5c20ceb07715216d3c217b7a",
        "restaurantName": "Thai Food Thai Now Sutera Mall",
        "type": [],
        "currency": "RM",
        "costPerPax": 16,
    }
]
```

#### expected result

I need the 'type' fields has match tag name from another collection like this

```
[
    {
        "id": "5c20c7a0036dda80a8baabcc",
        "restaurantName": "Villagio Restaurant Sutera Mall",
        "type": "Western",
        "currency": "RM",
        "costPerPax": 22,
    },
    {
        "id": "5c20ceb07715216d3c217b7a",
        "restaurantName": "Thai Food Thai Now Sutera Mall",
        "type": "Thai",
        "currency": "RM",
        "costPerPax": 16,
    }
]
```

#### Extra Information

two document from restaurants collection

```
    {
        "details": {
            "restaurantName": "Villagio Restaurant Sutera Mall",
            "restaurantType": "5c01fb57497a896d50f498a8"
        },
        "_id": "5c20c7a0036dda80a8baabcc",
        "status": "OP",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "details": {
            "restaurantName": "Kingshahi Japanese Shop",
            "restaurantType": "5c01fb57497a896d50f49879"
        },
        "_id": "5c20cb4fb7e75180480690c2",
        "status": "OP",
        "__v": 0
    }
```

One document from tag collection

```
        {
            "_id": "5c01fb57497a896d50f49876",
            "details": {
                "restaurantTypeId": "5c01fb57497a896d50f49877",
                "restaurantTypes": [
                    {
                        "_id": "5c01fb57497a896d50f49879",
                        "name": "Asian",
                        "counter": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5c01fb57497a896d50f4987a",
                        "name": "Bakery",
                        "counter": 0
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your `foreignField` value is incorrect. It should be `foreignField: "details.restaurantTypes._id",`

Comment: wow, thanks, now I manage to get some result out of the database, but I got the whole tag documents in each return object's "type" field, I tried the filter but it gave me [ ] in results. Do you see any error in my $filter query?

Comment: Your foreignField is an array that's why you are getting whole tags element. BTW what version of mongo you are using?

Comment: I am using db version v4.0.4

Comment: Great Could you post the sample json documents from both the collections. So that I can simply copy past it to reproduce the output

Comment: I think I will need more time to get the result from the database. I will come back in 10 mins

Comment: Okay, here you go

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use below optimised aggregation pipeline

```
db.restaurants.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "tags",
    "let": { "restaurantType": "$details.restaurantType" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": {
        "$expr": { "$in": ["$$restaurantType", "$details.restaurantTypes._id"] }
      }},
      { "$unwind": "$details.restaurantTypes" },
      { "$match": {
        "$expr": { "$eq": ["$details.restaurantTypes._id", "$$restaurantType"] }
      }}
    ],
    "as": "types"
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "restaurantName": "$details.restaurantName",
    "restaurantType": "$details.restaurantType",
    "type": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$types.details.restaurantTypes.name", 0] },
    "currency": "$details.currency",
    "costPerPax": "$details.costPerPax"
  }}
])
```

Comment: Hi, cool answer! I got this error when adding it to my query, would you mind look at it ? :)

error: MongoError: $in requires an array as a second argument, found: missing

Comment: Because some of your fields might not contain the `restarantTypes` array. Could you please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51642472/in-requires-an-array-as-a-second-argument-found-missing

Comment: Whoa, hahaha I changed my database already. I havent check the latest answer, but the previous one work like magic :) Thank you very much! I have seen your name appeared every where, and I thank you for you amazing help! you are a genius in Mongodb!