# Mongodb: can I compare if value in one field is contained in another field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Suppose I have a collection a called `collection_a` that contains a lookup to a collection b called `collection_b`.  If the collection contains a field called `primary_color` and the lookup contains a field called `available_colors`.  How can I compare `primary_color` to `available_colors` to see if the current value for `primary_color` is contained in the `available_colors` list?

I tried the following but it did not work in a aggregate match,

```
{'primary_color': {'$in': '$collection_b.available_colors'}}.
```

Comment: you may need to use `aggregate` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53966763/mongodb-lookup-on-one-documents-array-of-object)

Comment: you can use aggregation expressions in `find` queries with https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html

Comment: Or get all the available_colors and store them in a variable and use that in this query.

Comment: This is within a $match in an aggregate.

Answer (score 8):

It is not possible to refer another collection in `$match` stage.

You have to use `$lookup` or populate in mongoose.

```
db.collectiona.aggregate([
  {"$lookup":{
    "from":collectionb,
    "localField":"primary_color",
    "foreignField":"available_colors",
    "as":"matches"
  }},
  {"$match":{"matches.0":{"$exists":true}}}
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/bkQzZcrP0aJ