# MongoDB how to $project (limit fields) from the $lookup remote collection?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to $lookup for a remote collection like SQL Join but with Mongo. And I don't want all of the keys from the remote document to be pulled to the origin collection - just some specific keys.

This is what I have tried:

```
[
  {
    $lookup: {
        from: "tables",
        localField: "type",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "type"
      }
    },
    {
      $unwind: "$type"
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "type.title": 1
    }
  }
]
```

However this prints only "type.title" and ignores all of other keys even from the origin document.

Is there any way to tell MongoDB to pull only specific fields from the remote collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation with mongodb **3.6** and above

```
[
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "tables",
    "let": { "type": "$type" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$addFields": { "owners": { "$cond": { "if": { "$ne": [ { "$type": "$owners" }, "array" ] }, "then": [], "else": "$owners" } } }},
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$_id", "$$type"] }}},
      { "$project": { "title": 1 }}
    ],
    "as": "type"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$type" }
]
```

Comment: Thanks works very good. In order to search in array we can use `$in` (just in addition to what you have provided).

Comment: if I have this: `{ $match: { $expr: { $in: ["$_id", "$$owners"] }}}`
and owners is not exists in the origin collection. I have this error: `MongoError: $in requires an array as a second argument, found: missing` Do you know how I can set this only wheter owners exists and has more than one item in the array?

Comment: Please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51642472/in-requires-an-array-as-a-second-argument-found-missing

Comment: this is how I made it: `$lookup: {
      from: "users",
      let: { "owners": "$owners" },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $in: ["$$owners", "$_id"] }}},
        { $project: { status: 1, personal_info: 1 }}
      ],
      as: "owners"
    }` but unfortunately I am not able to make this working - even after looking at the question that you provided. Should cond be part of the pipeline as a stage?

Comment: `db.collection.update(
  { "owners": { "$type": { "$ne": "array" } } },
  { "$set": { "owners": [] } },
  { "multi": true }
)` use this query

Comment: Is there any solution that can make it working without predefining the array?

Comment: use this stage inside the lookup pipeline `{ "$addFields": {
    "owners": {
      "$cond": {
        "if": {
          "$ne": [ { "$type": "$owners" }, "array" ]
        },
        "then": [],
        "else": "$owners"
      }
    }
  }},`

Comment: That is just perfect. Could you please post this now as a full answer so others can easily understand the full solution of the $project? I think this will be more clear for other readers.