# MongoDB - Apply similar lookup on multiple columns in main table

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm a newbie to MongoDB, I'm trying to aggregate complete details of students in referencing with other collections.

**`students` collection structure:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cc973dd008221192148177a"),
    "name" : "James Paulson",
    "teachers" : [ 
        ObjectId("5cc973dd008221192148176f"), 
        ObjectId("5cc973dd0082211921481770")
    ],
    "attenders": [ 
        ObjectId("5cc973dd0082211921481732"), 
        ObjectId("5cc973dd008221192148173f")
    ]
}
```

**`staff` collection structure:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cc973dd008221192148176f"),
    "name" : "John Paul",
    "subject" : [ 
        "english", 
        "maths"
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cc973dd0082211921481771"),
    "name" : "Pattrick",
    "subject" : [ 
        "physics", 
        "history"
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cc973dd0082211921481732"),
    "name" : "Roger",
    "subject" : [ 
        "sweeper"
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cc973dd008221192148173f"),
    "name" : "Ken",
    "subject" : [ 
        "dentist"
    ]
}
```

This is the query I used for the retrieval of all teacher details of a particular student.

**Query:**

```
db.getCollection('students').aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$teachers"
  },      
  {
    $lookup:
    {
        from: 'staff',
        localField: 'teachers',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'teachers'
    }
  }
]);
```

**Result:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cc973dd008221192148177a"),
    "name" : "James Paulson",
    "teachers" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5cc973dd008221192148176f"),
            "name" : "John Paul",
            "subject" : [ 
                "english", 
                "maths"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5cc973dd008221192148176f"),
            "name" : "Pattrick",
            "subject" : [ 
                "physics", 
                "history"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "attenders": [ 
        ObjectId("5cc973dd0082211921481732"), 
        ObjectId("5cc973dd008221192148173f")
    ]
}
```

As you can see, the `attenders` array is also similar to `teachers` except the difference in column name in students table. So how to applying a similar query to the second column (`attenders`)? Also is there any way to select specific columns from the second table (like only `_id` and `name` from `staff` collection)?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below aggregation with mongodb **3.6** and above

Firstly you don't need to use [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) here as your field already contains array of `ObjectId`s. And to select the specific field from the referenced collection you can use the custom [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) with pipeline and [**`$project`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) the fields inside it.

```
db.getCollection('students').aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "staff",
    "let": { "teachers": "$teachers" },
    "pipeline": [
       { "$match": { "$expr": { "$in": [ "$_id", "$$teachers" ] } } }
       { "$project": { "name": 1 }}
     ],
     "as": "teachers"
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "attenders",
    "let": { "attenders": "$attenders" },
    "pipeline": [
       { "$match": { "$expr": { "$in": [ "$_id", "$$attenders" ] } } }
     ],
     "as": "attenders"
  }}
])
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I'm getting an error,

`Error: command failed: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "$in requires an array as a second argument, found: missing",
 "code" : 40081,
 "codeName" : "Location40081"
} : aggregate failed ` Is this a problem with the data?

Comment: yessss.   Pls have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51642472/in-requires-an-array-as-a-second-argument-found-missing