# MongoDB Aggregation: Use field value of current document in $match $or query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have an aggregation pipeline and my documents are currently in the following format :

```
{
    "user": "5e3d326537df7e4dda73eb23",
    "sharedWithGroups": [ "5e3d326437df7e4dda73eb13", "5e3d326437df7e4dda73eb19" ],
    "userGroupIds": [ "5e3d326437df7e4dda73eb19" ]
}
```

Where `userGroupIds` is the result of a previous stage, where I find the IDs of the groups that the user is in.

I'm trying to add a match stage to the pipeline to find all documents which have either a user ID that matches a specific ID, OR have a `sharedWithGroups` property that contains one of the entries in `userGroupIds`.

I thought that something like this would work :

```
{
  $match: {
    $or: [
      { user: "5e3d326537df7e4dda73eb23" },
      { sharedWithGroups: { $in: "$userGroupIds" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

But I get an error: `$in needs an array`. I don't understand because `$userGroupIds` is definitely an array. I've tried using $expr, thinking that the field value may not be resolving, but have had no luck. Is this approach possible, or is there another/better way to filter these documents using multiple criteria?

Comment: Note the difference between [$in (aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/index.html) and [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/index.html)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit ah, yes – I missed that difference, thanks!

Comment: Also note, `$in` takes an expression and an array. However, you like to compare two arrays, thus you have to use `$setIntersection` or `$setIsSubset`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this :

```
{
    $match: {
        $or: [
            { user: "5e3d326537df7e4dda73eb23" },
            { $expr: { $gt: [{ $size: { $setIntersection: ["$sharedWithGroups", "$userGroupIds"] } }, 0] } }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NftEckty-eP)

*(Or)*

```
{
    $match: {
        $or: [
            { user: "5e3d326537df7e4dda73eb23" },
            { $expr: { $setIsSubset: ["$userGroupIds", "$sharedWithGroups"] } }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PkAolzmlWdb)

Comment: Your first answer worked perfectly, thanks! I first had to ensure that the $sharedWithGroups field always exists, using a $cond in an $addFields stage before this stage, as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51642472/in-requires-an-array-as-a-second-argument-found-missing. Your second answer would work if my data were slightly different, but I can't guarantee one will be a subset of the other. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Craig : Yes this answer basically targets to sample data provided, please update according to actual data, Also you can do `$cond` in match itself like this :: https://mongoplayground.net/p/7qI7zKyUyEq , Instead of another `$addFields` stage..