# $nin condition inside $sum for a nested value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I am making a chat application using `nodejs` and `mongodb`. Currently I have multiple collections for users, rooms and messages. Each message contains a reference to a room, sender and an array of references to users who have read the message.

I am trying to get a count of unread messages for the current user using mongodb's aggregation. This is my current code:

```js
Room.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { participants: request.currentUser._id },
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'messages',
            localField: '_id',
            foreignField: 'room',
            as: 'messages',
        },
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: '$messages',
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
        },
    },
    {
        $sort: { 'messages.createdAt': -1 },
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$_id',
            name: { $first: '$name' },
            type: { $first: '$type' },
            participants: { $first: '$participants' },
            latestMessage: { $first: '$messages' },
            createdAt: { $first: '$createdAt' },
            updatedAt: { $first: '$updatedAt' },
            unreads: {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: {
                        if: {
                            $nin: [request.currentUser._id, '$messages.read']
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
        },
    },
])
```

This code always throws `Unrecognized expression '$nin'` error. How can I use such condition inside of the `$sum` to get the appropriate result?

Sample message document as request by @Ashh:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ef0796fdb424a92c4200cdd"),
    "read" : [ 
        ObjectId("5ef078df7ce82f2e5cf3b586")
    ],
    "content" : "Test message",
    "sender" : ObjectId("5ef078df7ce82f2e5cf3b586"),
    "room" : ObjectId("5ed4ffcdd13f45b4104a1669"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-06-22T09:27:11.017Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-06-22T09:27:11.017Z")
}
```

And also a sample room document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ed4ffcdd13f45b4104a1669"),
    "participants" : [ 
        ObjectId("5ed4ffbcd13f45b4104a1667"), 
        ObjectId("5ef078df7ce82f2e5cf3b586")
    ],
    "pending" : [],
    "name" : "Global",
    "type" : "CHANNEL",
    "creator" : ObjectId("5ed4ffbcd13f45b4104a1667"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-06-01T13:17:01.935Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-06-01T13:17:01.935Z")
}
```

Comment: have you tried [Op.nin]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$nin` is not an aggregation operator, however [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) is, and you can reverse the logic using `$in`

[$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) has two syntaxes

> `{ $cond: { if: <boolean-expression>, then: <true-case>, else: <false-case> } }`

and

> `{ $cond: [ <boolean-expression>, <true-case>, <false-case> ] }`

We need to replace the true case with 0 and the false case with 1, since we will count the cases that is *not* in the array

```
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            { $in: [request.currentUser._id, "$messages.read"] },
            0, // add 0 if in array
            1 // add 1 if not in array
          ]
        }
```

If `messages.read` does not exists, it will cause an error, so you should better wrap it with `$ifNull`

```
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            { $in: [request.currentUser._id, { $ifNull:[ "$messages.read", []] }] },
            0, // add 0 if in array
            1 // add 1 if not in array
          ]
        }
```

Comment: As I already commented on @Ashh's post, messages.read always exists but it still throws an error that it's missing, curious to what could be causing such issue

Comment: Hmm, yeah, that could actually be the issue because one room doesn't have any messages. Didn't even think about that scenario

Comment: Actually `$ifNull` should already account for that, are you sure you have tried with `$ifNull` ?

Comment: Yeah, that works except it returns 1 as the sum when there's no messages in a room

Comment: You mentioned there is always at least one read for every message right? I assume it's the sender? Maybe we could work from that

Comment: Yeah, every time a user sends a message it gets added to the read array of that message

Answer (score 1):

`$nin` is query operator and you have to use aggregation operator inside the `$group` . So instead use `$not` with `$in`

```
{ $not:{ $in: [request.currentUser._id, { $ifNull: ['$messages.read', []] }] } }
```

Comment: And from the room as well

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: @TheNeosrb see it is working https://mongoplayground.net/p/U0-c2QSchiC

Comment: It's not working, still the error from before where it says it missing

Comment: I am sure you have some documents which either do not contain the `read` field or do not have the type of `read` as an array. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51642472/in-requires-an-array-as-a-second-argument-found-missing

Comment: Struggling with that to be honest, none of my documents have the read as null or as any other type. They are all arrays with each one having a single ObjectID which is very strange. Maybe I am missing something in the group or the lookup